# Загрузка фото с локального компьютера на сайт

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем привет. Задача такая. Есть папка на локальном компе. Нужно брать определенные фотки и загружать их на сайт посредством php.
Т.Е. раньше я реализовывал так.

```
<form method="POST" action="/add_image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name='file[]' type='file' multiple='true' class="add_photo_input" />
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить" />
</form>

//Обработчик
if (isset($_FILES))
{
  //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
  {
    //Назначаем имя изображения

    //Проверка расширений загружаемых изображений
    if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/gif" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" ||
    $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
    {
      //черный список типов файлов
      $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
      foreach ($blacklist as $item)
      {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
        {
          //echo "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
          exit;
        }
      }

      //перемещаем файл из временного хранилища
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
      {
        //получаем размеры файла
        $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
        //проверяем размеры файла, если они нам подходят, то оставляем файл
        if ($size[0] < $pic_weight && $size[1] < $pic_height)
        {
             //я обычно заношу пути к изображениям в бд

        }

        else
        {
          unlink($uploadfile);
        }
      }
     }

  }
}
```

Так вот, а если вместо загрузки я указываю путь, то мне надо что бы он брал фото по этому пути с локального компа и грузил. Как это сделать?

Comment: Браузер без явного выбора файла пользователем не должен его отправлять на сайт. Иначе получаем огромную дыру в безопасности.

Comment: ну я выбираю, точнее указываю путь к файлу, раньше я выбирал фото, а сейчас я тупо пишу путь к файлу, и его надо загрузить

Comment: @duddeniska без действия пользователя (как указал Visman) ничего не будет происходить... "выбирать файл"  и " указывать путь" - это две разные вещи!

Comment: @Arsen Хорошо, вы можете подсказать тогда, как отрабатывает вот это http://web-data-extractor.net/parser-opencart-export/. Т.е. он парсер делает, фото сохраняет, а потом можно загружать в opencart Товары с фото.

Comment: @duddeniska   там же написано что данный парсинг производится из сайта источника (донор)... я там не заметил возможность загрузки файла с локального компа!! Возможно там сразу  настраивается FTP доступ на хостинг куда и сохраняются файлы и т.д.  И ещё, если это программа, которую можно скачать, работает  на WINDOWS, то конечно сама программа уже имеет доступ к локальным папкам компьютера... но это же к PHP не относится

Comment: @Arsen Ну я начал юзать эту прогу. Она сохраняет данные в excel, наименование фоток в excel. А фотки в папку изображения Посмотрите первый пункт как он отрабатывает. Он загружает из excel

Comment: Ну для  меня эта прога вообще не известна )) я просто логику знаю.... ну если софт сохраняет картинки на компьютер, это значит что программа написана для WINDOWS и конечно она сможет сделать эти действия, но как уже написал это не связанно с PHP и те же действия вы не сможете сделать посредством PHP )

Comment: @Arsen фиг знает, если фото выгружает, то можно же как то их загружать? иначе для чего это все далалось) Свяжусь с технарями проги может помогут